# How to set observer for monitoring customer in magento?

Tags: magento

I want the following things

1.If customer already exist dnt save(0) 
2.If customer is new then save it save(1)
3.If customer information change then save with update status save(2)

where save is a function,

In this case what should be the events.

Need solution.

I guess
customer_register_success
customer_save_after
adminhtml_customer_save_after

etc. please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the code lines around line 332 in app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php :

```
if (true === $validationResult) {
    $customer->save();

    Mage::dispatchEvent('customer_register_success',
        array('account_controller' => $this, 'customer' => $customer)
    );
```

You will see that customer_register_success if fired after $customer->save(), so makes no sense to observe both in this case.

If you set up your observer in config.xml in the "global" node, it will observe front- and backend, no need for the adminhtml event :

```
<global>
    <events>
        <customer_save_after>
            <observers>
            .... your custom code, i assume you know how to deal with it...
            </observers>
        </customer_save_after>
    </events>
</global>
```